AH01071: PHP Warning: ftp_get(): PORT command is disabled in
I've run this script before on another server without problems but getting the following error in my logs:

AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning: ftp_get(): PORT command
is disabled in /path/to/file

The script results in "There was a problem"....
The code should connect to an external FTP server to download a specific file and place it locally on my server. The connection is made and the login is successful. It is this line that causes the problem:
if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file)) {

Full Code:
<?php

$server_file = "testfile.xml.gz";
$local_file = 'tfs.xml.gz';
$ftp_server="aftp.xxx.com";
$ftp_user_name="xxx_xxxx";
$ftp_user_pass="xxxxx";

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// try to download $server_file and save to $local_file
if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file)) {
    echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";
}
else {
    echo "There was a problem\n";
}
// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);

?>


I have disabled my firewall temporarily but it made no difference.
The local file has 777 permissions.
The remote server's owner's only
stipulation is to use Binary transfer mode.
I can connect fine via Filezila and download the file.
My server is Plesk Obsidian if that is relevant.

Any ideas gratefully received...

You say the login is successful, but you never check the $login_result boolean.

ftp_pasv() should prevent the need for the PORT command. Since you use that function, I don't see why you're getting this warning.

According to this question ftp_pasv() should be after ftp_login().

I couldn't amend anything because the question was closed but @Barmar was correct. Moving the ftp_pasv() fixed the problem.
